# MySQL events doesn't run eventhough every settings is enable

Tags: mysql, database, events

I have created simple `event` but it doesn't run:

```
  DELIMITER |
  CREATE EVENT myevent3
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 second
      STARTS current_timestamp()
    ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    DO
      BEGIN
        UPDATE hiberante.animal SET name = name + 'a' where id = 6;
      END |
DELIMITER ;
```

I have done:
`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`
Also done:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS;
```

[image]
and

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.event;
```

[image]

And it still doesn't want to start working.

In my process list:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

[image]

Comment: `+` isn't string concatenation in MySQL, use `CONCAT(name, 'a')`

Comment: That query will run so quickly that you're not likely to see it running when you do `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

Comment: What timezone is the server in? Is it after `18:23` in that zone?

Comment: @Barma I have changed it into after posting the question, forgot to change:
`STARTS current_timestamp()`

Comment: You're still not going to see it in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` unless you're very lucky.